# How can I increase icon/thumbnail size in Finder list view in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, icons, finder, macos-bigsur

I would like to increase the icon size in Finder list view, as seen in the screenshot below].

I set it to the max in view settings and tried editing `com.apple.finder.plist` already, but without any result.

It’s driving me nuts, because I don’t really like using other views, but often can’t see much in the list view.

[image: Screenshot of the Finder list view with the icons whose size I want to increase.]

Comment: Doesn't [this procedure](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/make-it-easier-to-see-whats-on-the-screen-mchld786f2cd/11.0/mac/11.0) work?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately no - I have it set to the max already. I would like to increase it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the icon size brings the desired effect. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and set the icon size to the [larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRk9D.png).